# LISTVIEW ÍTEM EXTRA NO DESEADO

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

Buenas, cree una aplicación en Android studio, la cual maneja ListView, sin embargo, descubrí que en el principio del ListView tengo un ítem oculto el cual no está declarado, no existe en mi código, pero es un botón, el cual no cumple ningúna función. Adjunto una captura del botón para que puedan verlo mejor.Como pueden ver arriba de noticias figura ese espacio, que únicamente es visible cuando se presiona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Codigo Layout:

---

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/background_material_dark" />
```

---

CODIGO DEL MENU:

---

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_7"
    android:icon="@drawable/clipboard_text"
    android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_7" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_category_1"
    android:title="@string/navigation_view_category_1"
    android:textStyle="bold">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_6"
            android:icon="@drawable/office"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_6" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/voice"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
            android:icon="@drawable/code_string"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_3" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_category_2"
    android:title="@string/navigation_view_category_2"
    android:textStyle="bold">
    <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_4"
                android:icon="@drawable/account_card_details"
                android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_4" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_5"
                android:icon="@drawable/youtube"
                android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_5" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_8"
                android:icon="@drawable/twitter"
                android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_8" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_9"
                android:icon="@drawable/facebook"
                android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_9" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_10"
                android:icon="@drawable/solar_panel"
                android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_10" />
</menu>
</item>
<!--<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_8"
    android:icon="@drawable/maps"
    android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_8" />-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_category_3"
    android:title="@string/navigation_view_category_3"
    android:textStyle="bold">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_11"
            android:icon="@drawable/information"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_11" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_12"
            android:icon="@drawable/email"
            android:title="@string/navigation_view_item_12" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

---

Comment: Juan, el código siempre será necesario. Por favor publicanlo tanto del layout como del menú e intenta ser mas específico de cual el elemento que no quieres que aparezca

Comment: @Einer añadi el codigo fuente, nose porque razon se me corta la ultima linea de codigo, de todas formas no son importantes ya que solo faltan el cierre del menu y del layout. Y remarque cual es el "objeto" que aparece al comienzo del listview.

Answer (score 2):

Ese item "oculto" en realidad es un `WebView` que tienes dentro del `CoordinatorLayout`, elimina el `WebView`:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Generalmente el `WebView` en vista de diseño se pinta de color gris.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad que no me manejo con el modo de diseño, pero cuando me dijiste revise y no parece ser el webview. Parece que el headerLayout es lo que ahi aparece, lo solvente añadiendo la etiquetal al XML y seteandolo en 0px, asi desaparecio y recupere el espacio